# Notepad++: disabling keyboard shortcuts that change EOL convention for a specific line (Ctrl+M for Mac, Ctrl+J for UNIX)

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ has keyboard shortcuts **built-in** that can change the end-of-line convention *for a specific line alone*.  This means one can inadvertently create a MIXED format file by accidentally typing the shortcut:

```
- Ctrl+M inserts a Mac style EOL character (i.e. 0x0D only) *on just that line*,
- Ctrl+J puts a UNIX style EOL character (i.e. (0x0A only) *on just that line*,
```

**Question:** Can these keyboard shortcuts be disabled or changed?

(I've scanned through `Settings > Shortcut Mapper` and could not find Ctrl+M or Ctrl+J listed for EOL conversion.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are built in, but not in notepad++. Try it with plain notepad, or any other app, it will still work. They are common control ascii codes (that's where `ctrl` on that key comes from). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> will be decoded as `0A` by keyboard controller/driver (similarly for other `Ctrl` combinations). 
More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_characters

Comment: Well, that was a completely unexpected (but enlightening) explanation! (+1)  Making it explicit: `Control+[KEY]` is implemented as subtracting `64d` (decimal) or `0x40` from the ASCII value of the capital letter `[KEY]`.  So since `ascii(M) = 77d`, `ctrl+M = 13d = 0x0D`, and since `ascii(J) = 74d`, `ctrl+J = 10d = 0x0A`...

Comment: Hmmm... so how can this be protected against?

Comment: @ake You probably could re-map the key combination in Windows (as the process in reality is more complex). I can't suggest particular product or procedure as I have not used them, but searching 'windows remap keyboard' brings many.

Comment: Imposing such a global setting change on a system seems a bit too drastic.  I think this would be best handled by a "usability feature" within Notepad++ to protect the integrity of source code files from ending up with mixed EOL formats.  What do you think of not allowing different EOL formats for different lines?  This could be implemented by trapping `Ctrl+M` and `Ctrl+J` and, if the file level EOL format is not set to either Mac or Unix respectively, then Notepad++ would suppress the characters (possibly issuing a notice the first time).  Worth a bug / feature request to NPP?

Comment: @Ake I personally hate if  a tool 'knows better' and does not allow me to do something, so I would rather opt for a message on open/save warning about inconsistent eol and offering option to normalize them. That's only me, though. As for requesting new feature - it's your call, but I can't see why not.

Comment: Like your suggestion (open/save warning, option to normalise).  Put in something already around this issue.  Once it is assigned to someone, will modify to add these suggestions.

Comment: @AKE They're also the 13th and 10th letters of the alphabet, respectively. Some people might find this easier than doing hexadecimal calculations with ASCII codes ;-)